# Тело POST-запроса

Tags: http, https

Подскажите пожалуйста, у POST-запроса обязательно должно быть тело запроса или может быть только URL ?

Answer (score 1):

Если Вам правильно понял
Можно только url
по примеру так

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type='submit' value='Send'>
</form>
```